# parameter not passed to a dynamic query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to pass a parameter to a dynamic query but it does not work. The parameter is defined in this report. The following works:

```
select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=@zloze
```

the following does not:

```
declare @PytanieSQL nvarchar(max); 
set @PytanieSQL='select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=@zloze' 
exec sp_executesql @PytanieSQL
```

In the example below it asks me to declare the scalar variable @zloze.
This is strange as other forum postings indicate this should work.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Added:
maybe this will shed some light: after I incidentally opened the query designer from this Dataset's properties window I got a message "The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported." I'm using Studio 2013

Comment: Have you tried using an expression to define your dynamic query? Then you can build up the string, as per ="SELECT naz_zloze from Slo_zloze WHERE id_zloze=" & Parameters!Myparam.Value or similar.

Comment: using an expression won't work. The query here is just a simple example, The actual query is much more complex, but when it did not work I tried the idea on a simple example where there would be minimal room for mistake

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of `@zlose` is numeric then

```
declare @PytanieSQL nvarchar(max); 
set @PytanieSQL='select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=' + @zloze
exec sp_executesql @PytanieSQL
```

If `@zlose` is a string then

```
declare @PytanieSQL nvarchar(max); 
set @PytanieSQL='select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=''' + @zloze + '''
exec sp_executesql @PytanieSQL
```

Comment: @zloze is an Integer, but unfortunately your code does not work. When  after updating the query I close the Dataset Properties window with OK or hit the Refresh Fields button a "Define Query Parameters" window pops up and the dataset does not return any fields.BTW this solution is proposed in some other topic as well and I'd tried it before. Could the problem be with the Visual Studio version? I'm using 2013.

Comment: This should work fine. The first thing I would do is test it in SSMS. Assuming it works OK there then next I would temporarily change the last line to `SELECT @PytanieSQL` so you can see exactly what is being executed.

Comment: It works in SSMS and the result of select looks OK: ' select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=1 ' ie. after I declared '@zloze varchar(1)='1' '. In SSRS a Define Query Parameters window pops out. Needless to say, I have defined @zloze as a parameter (text)in my report and the user is to be prompted to enter a value

Comment: You said @zlose was an integer originally. It should be defined as an integer in your report and then you'll need to cast it back to varchar in your SQL `'select naz_zloze from Slo_zloze where id_zloze=' + cast(@zloze as varchar(10))` . Having said all this, is there a good reason why you are using dynamic sql?

Comment: I have tried both integer and varchar, made no difference. This query here is an example. I got stuck in my actual query so I worked it down to this very simplified form to make it easier to find the mistake. I need to use dynamic sql because in my actual dataset I have to be able to call dynamic table names. In the database tables are dynamically created and named and value of @zloze is a part of such name. BTW I have seen other postings in this forum regarding passing dynamic table names and tried them without success